# Why do modules imported inside their package bring in their own module name

Tags: python, module, python-import

I have a simple structure:

```
\package
  \__init__.py
  \module1.py
```

Inside `__init__.py` I have:

```
from . import module1 as another_name
print(dir())
```

When I open an interpreter and run `import Test` I will find that my namespace includes both `module1` *and* `another_name`. Why does `module1` appear in my namespace, when I've explictly told Python to call it something else?